# Semantic UI - Transparent Simple Dropdown on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2, semantic-ui

Implemented a drop-down menu using Semantic UI. Working as expected for most platforms except iOS, where the menu flashes and is then replaced by the content in the body of the HTML. This is my first time working with Semantic UI. Any suggestions for how to debug this?

See the attached animated gif.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the opacity of the drop-down is being reduced. The content is not changing.

Comment: Makes sense. Are you suggesting that I set the opacity to 100% (I think I'm using the default opacity settings)?

Comment: The opacity is the symptom, so I suggest you investigate how that’s being set or changed.